# Are browser (firefox) settings/passwords preserved in upgrading Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, firefox

I have backed-up my files and am ready to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS. I was wondering if my firefox password/history/etc will be preserved or wiped?

Comment: Yes, configs for most applications (including `firefox`) should survive, as long as you backup and restore your `$HOME` properly.  Personally I store `/home` on its own partition on all systems I use, precisely to keep it safe across system upgrades.

Answer (score 2):

Your complete Firefox profile, including settings, bookmarks, history, passwords, installed add-ons, etc. is stored in your home directory in the folder

```
~/.mozilla/firefox/<PROFILE-NAME>
```

where `<PROFILE-NAME>` is normally composed of 8 random letters and a `.default` suffix.

There is also the file `~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini` though which lists the configured profiles of the user account and defines which one should be used by default when you start Firefox without parameters. You can easily recreate this one, but it's easier if you just back it up as well.

Anyway, if you backed up your complete home directory, all your Firefox user data and settings will be preserved.